# Installation of Perl Packages is failing on CentOS 5, 64-bit

Tags: perl, cpan

I am trying to install DBD::mysql and I am getting thousands of warnings and errors when I install like this:

```
perl -MCPAN -e 'install DBD::mysql'
```

The errors are like:

```
dbdimp.c:3215 error: 'imp_sth_t' has no member named 'warning_count'
```

Then at the end it says:

```
make had returned a bad status, install seems impossible
```

This also fails:

```
 perl -MCPAN -e 'install Geo::IP::PurePerl'
```

Comment: I can not answer your question but have you tried installing the RPM package for Centos? This is a popular package so I guess it s available as rpm.

Comment: In general, when you receive gcc-like errors from CPAN installations, you're missing a library dependency. Alexandr Ciornii below found a library that looks likely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

install perl-DBD-MySQL, or if don't want to install from rpm, install mysql-devel package first

Comment: I installed mysql-devel, and that fixed everything.

thanks.

do you know where you can look up where rpms of CPAN stuff it in the future?

Answer (score 2):

The `DBD::mysql` module can be a little tempermental. Look at the README and INSTALL.html files that came with your DBD-mysql distribution (typically in the ~/.cpan/build/DBD-mysql-XXXXX directory). [Here](http://cpansearch.perl.org/src/CAPTTOFU/DBD-mysql-3.0000/INSTALL.html) is a typical INSTALL.html file for this module.

Those files will have specific advice for installing the module for your operating system and the particular way you have MySQL installed on your machine.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing you don't have the MySQL client libraries and headers installed, which is breaking the compile. Try installing the mysqlclient RPMs first. Alternatively, see if there's an RPM package for the CPAN module that you can use.

Comment: that didn't seem to work.

I did

    yum install mysql

and ran

    perl -MCPAN -e 'install DBD::mysql'

again. It failed. Again.

Comment: this was helpful, but Alexandr completed the answer.